# How to trigger dependent: :destroy on a child only when grand-parent is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activemodel

When I delete `AdTemplate` record I do not want its connected `page_view_stats data` to be deleted also. But when I delete a `Campaign` record I **do** want `ad_templates` also delete all its page_view_stats records. Maybe dependent: :destroy can accept some :if condition to achieve it?

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ad_templates, dependent: :destroy
end

class AdTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :campaign
 has_many :page_view_stats
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use after_destroy callback in Campaign

`after_destroy do
    # execute some logic
end`